# Implementing container based security in tomcat using sql server 2005

Tags: tomcat6, jdbcrealm

I have been trying to implement container based security in tomcat 6.0 using sql server 2005. It worked fine using tomcat-user.xml file, but when i change the realm to sql server it throws an error. I have gone through almost everything on google, but no help. Can anybody please guide me to some sure shot path that will help me fix this problem. This is what my realm looks like

> <Realm
>   className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
>            debug="99" 
>            driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
>
> connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://mindfield-pc:1138;databaseName=College;user=sa;password=sa;SelectMethod=Cursor"
>          connectionName="sa"
>   connectionPassword="sa" digest="SHA"
>            userTable="Users" userNameCol="username"
>   userCredCol="password"
>            userRoleTable="Roles" roleNameCol="rolename"/>

I have checked that my sql server accepts sa username and password and NT Authority has been added to the security users. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Realm definition is *really* case-sensitive so make sure all values are in the correct case.

Good Luck!